# ui:InputRadio with event.getSource().getElement() doesn't work under Locker Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I was trying to use standard `ui:inputRadio` with `change="{!c.onRadio}"` attribute, precisely as in the below example from documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputRadio.htm

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="stages" type="String[]" default="Any,Open,Closed,Closed Won"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.stages}" var="stage">
        <ui:inputRadio label="{!stage}" change="{!c.onRadio}" />
    </aura:iteration>
   <b>Selected Item:</b>
   <p><ui:outputText class="result" aura:id="radioResult" value="" />
</aura:component>

({
    onRadio: function(cmp, evt) {
         var elem = evt.getSource().getElement();
         var selected = elem.textContent;
         resultCmp = cmp.find("radioResult");
         resultCmp.set("v.value", selected);
     }
})
```

It doesn't work under Locker Service, because secure DOM seems to lock `ui:inputRadio` component.

**Error:**
*Something has gone wrong. Action failed: c$XXX_LockerTestRadio$controller$onRadio [TypeError: evt.getSource(...).getElement is not a function] Failing descriptor: {c$XXX_LockerTestRadio$controller$onRadio}. Please try again.*

Can somebody suggest if this will be solved in the framework or we should plan some workaround?

I will put a workaround in the answer to that post, however it's quite unpleasant that things copied directly from documentation do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the line to get the value to

var selected = event.getSource().get("v.label");

you get the correct label. Always use a published API instead of reaching inside the component to look at the DOM.

Comment: Ok, this works also. At some stage it would be got to update documentation.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will file a bug for that.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that I found would be to use standard `input type="radio"` html tag:

Component:

```
<input type="radio" name="someUniqueName" onchange="{!c.onRadio}" value="{!val}"/></td>
```

Controller:

```
onRadio : function(cmp, evt) {
    var elem = evt.target;
    var selected = elem.value;
    ...
```